# Поиск max min значений одномерный массив C

Tags: c

```
srand(time(NULL));
int n;    
double *mas = NULL;
int index_max = 0; 
int index_min = 0;
printf("\n Vvedite razmer massiva: \n");
scanf("%d", &n);
// Allocate memory
mas = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
if (!mas) {
    printf("Not enough memory. Sorry :(\n");
    return 1;
}
// Fill array elements
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n * sizeof(double); i += sizeof(double), j++) 
{
    *(mas + i) = (double)(rand()%10000)/100;
    printf("%f ", *(mas + i));
}
// free(mas);
 return 0;

double max_elem = mas[0]; 
double min_elem = mas[0];

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < n * sizeof(double); i += sizeof(double), j++) 
{
    if (max_elem < mas[i])
    {
        max_elem = mas[i];
        index_max = i;
    }
    if (min_elem > mas[i])
    {
        min_elem = mas[i];
        index_min = i;
    }
}
printf("\n Min element = %f  Index = %f\n", min_elem, index_min); 
printf("\n Max element = %f  Index = %f\n", max_elem, index_max);
```

выводит только массив, min max и их индексы не выводит

Comment: А почему он должен что-то выводить, если до того у вас стоит `return 0`? BTW, вторая ошибка - `indedx_max` и `index_min` выводятся как `%f`, хотя они `int` (но ещё лучше для индексов массивов использовать `size_t`)

Comment: Попробуйте всё-таки воспользоваться отладчиком. Да нет, не "попробуйте", а запустите его и прогоните вашу программу пошагово, с просмотром переменных на каждом шаге.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ```
> for( ...; n * sizeof(double); i += sizeof(double)... )
> ```

умножение и прибавление `sizeof()` тут лишнее, при обращении к элементам массива компилятор сам учтет размер.

Comment: + совершенно непонятно что делает `j`. Но все эти вещи быстро и наглядно можно увидеть, если воспользоваться отладчиком, а не гадать на кофейной гуще...

Answer (score 0):

`return 0;` говорит о том, что после него код исполняться не будет.

Отладчик позволяет сэкономить время на задавании вопросов, да и вообще помогает в непонятных ситуациях.